# solving a two variable linear equation congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

Let $a_i$ and $N$ be a integer and equations $a_i x_i -y \equiv 0 \mod N$ are given. 
How can I solve these linear equation?

More precisely, I want to find a nontrivial pair $(x_i,y)$ such that $|x_i|,|y| \le \sqrt N$. For all i, it is impossible to exist solutions satisfying above conditon, but I think it is reasonable the existence of a pair.

(Edit) What I want to find is a nontrivial solution, and $N$ is sufficiently larger than $a_i$.
What should I do for finding a pair?

Comment: I'm confused, what are the givens and what are you trying to find? And why the constraint with $\sqrt N$.  You'll always have the trivial solution $x = y = 0$.  But you might not have nontrivial solutions, for example, if $N=3$ and $a = 2$.

Comment: @badam Baplan, Sorry, I have a mistake to simplify the problem. I will edit this problem.

Comment: @PiggyJin If it is a (single) two variable congruence, then what is $i$?  Why not just write $a$ instead of $a_i$?  Are there multiple values of $a_i$ for which you are looking a single $y$ that works simultaneously for all $i$?  If so, then the bound of $\sqrt N$ is unreasonable.

Comment: @BadamBaplan No, if $N=3$ and $a=2$ then take $x=1, y=-1$.

Comment: @Erick Wong, then $|y| = 2$ which is $> \sqrt 3$, that's why i mentioned it.  Or in general if $a = N-1$, then $x = -y$ are the nontrivial solutions and you cannot have both $|x|, |y| < \sqrt N$, that's why the OP had to add the "and $N$ is sufficiently larger than $a_i$" clause

Comment: @BadamBaplan How on earth do you arrive at $|y| = |{-1}| = 2$?  Absolute value makes sense for integers, not congruence classes.

Comment: Oop that's my bad if it's supposed to be an absolute value, was assuming it was lazy notation for lowest positive representative of congruence class.

Comment: @BadamBaplan This is a standard pigeonhole argument, though I haven't worked out whether the upper bound should be $\sqrt N$ or $\lceil sqrt{N} \rceil$ or somesuch.  But if you fix an integer $k$ then some pair of the residues $0,a,2a,\ldots ka$ must be at most $N/(k+1)$ apart.  So taking $k$ to be "around" $\sqrt{N}$ shows that there exists a solution where $x$ and $y$ are both at most (approximately) $k$.  The OP is looking for an efficient way to find such a pair.

Comment: @PiggyJin If $N$ is sufficiently large compared to $a$ then $(1,a)$ works :).  What exactly do you mean by sufficiently large?

Comment: @Erick Wong, well. I think $N$ is an $t^3$ bit integer if $a$ is also $t-bit integer$ with $t>2^10$.

Comment: @PiggyJin You should edit the question with these important details.  If so then $\lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor$ is a $t^3/2$-bit integer, which is **easily** larger than $a$ so the first non-trivial solution $(1,a)$ is fine.

Comment: @PiggyJin See [Thue's Lemma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%27s_lemma)